# Difference between Python multiprocessing Array and SharedMemory?

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, shared-memory

I need to share several numpy arrays between processes. I could use either multiprocessing Array or sharedmemory.SharedMemory to share the bulk of the data (the shapes and the dtypes are communicated separately). Any reason to choose one or the other?